# Jquery wrapAll ul li after paragraphs

Tags: jquery, html-lists, paragraphs, wrapall

I need to transform this :

```
<div id="truc">
   <p>First</p>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</li>
      <li>Item three</li>

  <p>Second</p>
    <li>Item four</li>
    <li>Item five</li>
    <li>Item six</li>
</div>
```

into this :

```
<div id="truc">
   <p>First</p>
    <ul id="list1">
       <li>Item one</li>
       <li>Item two</li>
       <li>Item three</li>
    </ul>

   <p>Second</p>
    <ul id="list2">
       <li>Item four</li>
       <li>Item five</li>
       <li>Item six</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to use wrapAll with jquery, something like that :

```
$('#truc p~li').each(function() {
   $(this).wrapAll('<ul>');
});
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated :) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *this* specific structure, you can use the following:

```
$('p', '#truc').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('p').wrapAll('<ul>');
});
```

Output ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/9ER59/)):

```
<div id="truc">
   <p>First</p>
   <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two</li>
      <li>Item three</li>
   </ul>
   <p>Second</p>
   <ul>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
      <li>Item six</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

---

As for the IDs, you can ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/9ER59/1/)):

```
$('p', '#truc').each(function(i) {
    $(this).nextUntil('p').wrapAll($('<ul>', {id: 'list' + (1 + i)}));
});
```

---

The problem with your original approach:

```
$('#truc p~li').each(function() {
   $(this).wrapAll('<ul>');
});
```

is that the selector `#truc p~li` mathces *all* `<li>` elements (not groupings for each `<p>` element) and thus wraps *each* item in the match (`<li>` element) with a `<ul>` element.